# Print a FullCalendar instance in v5

Tags: html, css, printing, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

downloaded for trial the v5.4.0 scheduler/adaptive plugin since the docs say "print optimization will work automatically".  Can someone help me out with how they go about "printing" a fullcalendar instance in their application?  my instance of fullcalendar is not the only <div...> on the page.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean you have other content on the page, but when you press Print you want only the calendar to print out? If so then you likely need a print-specific CSS in your page which makes sure all the other elements are hidden when in print mode. That's all I can suggest, without a clearer explanation of the situation.

Comment: Correct, i have a page with other content.  I would like to be able to just print just the calendar.

Comment: Ok so please do as I suggested above. You need some print-specific media queries. Really this question is nothing to do with fullCalendar, the same principle would apply to any page where you only want to print selected parts of it